# Is there anyway for Netfilter_queue to provide only control packets

Tags: networking, tcp, linux-kernel, netfilter

I am working on a project to provide ability to intercept
network connections originating from, and coming into Linux machines
at various stages during the network connections life-cycle.

These stages include the following:

1. Just before an outbound network connection is made - i.e. when the first SYN packet is sent out.
2. Just after an outbound network connection is established.
3. Just after the connection is terminated.
4. When an inbound connection is established - i.e. when the first SYN packet is received from outside.

For above requirements, I was evaluating netfilter_queue to get
the packets in the user-space and then decide the verdict whether to
allow or drop the packet.

My main concern here is, that once I am done with
netfilter_queue registration, I'll start getting all the packets. But
I am only interested in control packets and don't want data packets to
be sent to user-space.

So, my question is - Is there any existing way to tell the
netfilter_queue kernel module to send only the control packets and not
the data packets ? Also, would it be possible to get notified about
the connection establishment and termination ?

If there is no ready way to achive above, then would it make
sense to modify libnfnetfilter_queue and netfilter_queue kernel module
to provide only control packets depending upon the config mode set,
i.e. introducing NFQNL_COPY_CONTROL_PACKET for copying only control
packets to user-space ?

Sorry if my questions seems naive as I am still exploring netfilter_queue.

I posted the same question on netfilter mailing list also, but got no reply so far :(

Thanks for all the help.

Gaurav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make an iptables rule to add certain packets to the queue. You can make a rule that only queues the packets you want. For example:

```
ip6tables -I INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j QUEUE
```

The `--tcp-flags` options are described on this page: http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/packet-filtering-HOWTO-7.html#ss7.3